# Formula to reference dynamically named workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook that generates information based on what is imported/copied to a sheet (sheet3) within the same parent workbook (refer to as Generator). The information that is being imported/copied is coming from a sheet within a separate workbook (refer to as DATA). The name of the DATA workbook will always change and will never have a standard naming but will always be a *.csv file. What is an ideal way to automatically import/reference the values from the Data workbook into the Generator worksheet3?

I have tried using the INDEX function and replacing the name of the DATA file with a "*", but I have not been able to get this to work. I have tried to just outright reference the DATA file to test that my base formula was even working and had no issues. My guessing is that using formulas introduces dependencies into the logic, so this maybe may not work, or I am just lacking the knowledge to know what I am doing wrong.
Another thought is that a macro would best serve this task, though, I have limit knowledge on writing macros.

Comment: You can't use a wildcard to reference an external file in a formula - you need to use the full path.  If you don't know the name of the file then you can either use VBA or if the csv file is in a fixed location you can likely use Power Query to import its contents.

Comment: How would you write that VBA, if you don't mind me inquiring further? I would very much like to learn.

Comment: I also found this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Project.Project.UniqueID

Comment: Where is the DATA csv file?  In the same folder as the workbook it's being imported into?  Somewhere else?  Are there other csv files in that same location?

Comment: The DATA csv would be in a different subfolder within my program's parent folder. And there should only be one csv file at a given time, since once the program has finished, the DATA csv will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some advice from @Tim Williams and some additional researching from other posts on Stack, I came up with the following script. It may be excessive, but it is working flawlessly.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call Module1.CsvPath

End Sub

Sub CsvPath()

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range, r5 As Range, r6 As Range, r7 As Range, r8 As Range, r9 As Range, r10 As Range, o As Workbook, Path As String, root As String, f As String
    Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    Set r2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
    Set r3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
    Set r4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2")
    Set r5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2")
    Set o = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Module2.GetLocalPath & "\" & Module3.Test)
    Set r6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    Set r7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
    Set r8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
    Set r9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2")
    Set r10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2")
    
    [r1] = [r6]
    [r2] = [r7]
    [r3] = [r8]
    [r4] = [r9]
    [r5] = [r10]
    o.Close

End Sub

Function GetLocalPath() As String

    Dim sRowPath    As String
    Dim sLocalPath  As String
    Dim iFindhttp   As Integer
    Dim fso As New OLEObject
    
    sRowPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    If LCase(Left(sRowPath, 4)) = "http" Then
        sLocalPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(sRowPath)
        iFindhttp = InStr(LCase(sLocalPath), "\http")
        sLocalPath = Left(sLocalPath, iFindhttp - 1)
        Set fso = Nothing
    Else
        sLocalPath = sRowPath
    End If
            
    GetLocalPath = sLocalPath

End Function

Function Test()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFiles As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim X
Dim lngFileCnt As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim strBuffer1 As String
Dim strFolder As String

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
strFolder = Module2.GetLocalPath
Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(strFolder)
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
lngFileCnt = objFiles.Count
ReDim X(1 To lngFileCnt)

'grab all jpg files
For Each objFile In objFiles
    If Right$(objFile.Name, 3) = "csv" Then
        X = objFile.Name
    End If
Next

Test = X

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a csv file in a folder "data" stored in the same folder as the workbook where your code is running, then this UDF will reurn the path to that csv:

```
'return the full path to the first csv from folder `root`
Function CsvPath() As String
    Dim f As String, root As String
    root = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data\"
    f = Dir(root & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(f) > 0 Then CsvPath = root & f
End Function
```